# Biased random walk: Probability of hitting a value before some specified time.

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, conditional-probability, random-walk

**Question.** Suppose we have iid random variables $\{X_k\}_{k\geq 1}$ where
$$P(X_k = 1) = \frac{2}{3} \quad\text{and}\quad P(X_k = -1) = \frac{1}{3}.$$

We have the random walk $\{S_t\}_{t \geq 1}$ where

$$S_0 = 4, \quad S_t := S_0 + \sum_{k=1}^t X_k.$$

I'm trying to find the probability that we arrive at the value of $6$ before time $t = 8$. Formally, we want to find the probability that at any time, $1 \leq t \leq 7$, we have $S_t = 6$.

---

**What I have.** I think we can solve this using the recurrence relations
$$p_{t,i} = \frac{2}{3}p_{t-1,i+1} + \frac{1}{3}p_{t-1, i-1},$$

where $p_{t,i}$ is the conditional probability that at time $t$ we have value $i$. The obvious case is $p_{t,0} = 0$.

I'm unsure of how we do this. My intuition says we just find the sum of all possible instances that we can hit a value of 6 before time $t = 8$, i.e. $\sum_{t=2}^8 p_{t, 6}$?

Comment: A brutal approach I found $(2/3)^2 + 2*(2/3)^3(1/3) + 5*(2/3)^4(1/3)^2 + 14*(2/3)^5(1/3)^3 = 5380/6561 \approx 0.82$, perhaps that could help you check your work.

Comment: A python snippet to check: https://onecompiler.com/python/3xhgabmcp

Comment: @bonsoon Do you know of any combinatorics identity to find the valid combinations conditional on $t$ and $i$? It seems that these are Catalan numbers starting at $n=1$ for this example (i.e. 1, 2, 5, 14), but I don't see a general connection... which would be nice for when $i$ changes.

Comment: these are all related to some bounded height Dyck paths (and hence Catalan numbers), you might want to look them up.  I will have to work out the details, but not on top of my head.